# How do I change the color of p:schedule at certain hours in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, fullcalendar, schedule

I've been looking for a way to change the color of the p:schedule element in Primefaces at certain hours, but I just can't find one. For example, in the next image I would want the schedule to be light green instead of white from 13:00 to 14:00 : [schedule that i want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2iUQ.png).

I don't want to add different colored events, I only want to change the color of certain parts of the schedule to different colors.

So far I haven't found an attribute or something that I could use to change it that specifically.

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect the rows and cells with your browser's DOM inspector, you'll see that each cell has a `data-time` attribute containing the time:

[image: FullCalendar rendered cells]

Simply use those to add CSS rules. For example:

```css
td[data-time='13:00:00'],
td[data-time='13:10:00'],
td[data-time='13:20:00'] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

See also [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)